# How to display back button and hide Navigation Bar in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, button, hide, navigationbar, back

I am hiding the navigation bar like this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null       
};
```

but I want to display only the back button, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I managed to find the right solution:

```
     static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => { 
return { 
headerTitle: 
<Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18 }}>Test</Text>, headerTransparent: true, 
headerStyle: { borderBottomWidth: 0, } } 
}
```

I am only building in Android right now btu I would like to know if this works in iOS as well?